# sending variables to table PHP SQL

Tags: php, mysql

im trying to send my variables to table but i get error for $title and $body:

> Undefined variable: title in C:\wamp\www\source\pishnahad.php on line 237
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: body in C:\wamp\www\source\pishnahad.php on line 237

```
<div class='container' dir="rtl" >
<label for='name'>نام: </label>
<input type='text' name='name' id='name' value='<?=  $fgmembersite->UserFullName() ?>' maxlength="50"  disabled="disabled"/><br/>

</div>


<div class='container' dir="rtl" >
<label for='email'>ایمیل: </label>
<input type='text' name='email' id='email' value='<?= $fgmembersite->UserEmail() ?>' disabled="disabled"/><br/>

</div>

<form name="form2" method="post" action="submit_shekayat" accept-charset='UTF-8'>
<div class='container' dir="rtl" >
<label for='title'>موضوع: </label>
<input type='text' name='title' id='title'/><br/>

</div>

<div class='container' dir="rtl" >
<label for='body'>توضیحات: </label> <br />
<textarea name="body" id="body" cols="" rows="" style="width:300 ;height:300"></textarea>

</div>

            <?php

$user_id =$fgmembersite->UserID();

$db_host = 'localhost';
$db_name= 'site';
$db_table= 'shekayat';
$db_user = 'root';
$db_pass = '';




$con = mysql_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_pass) or die("خطا در اتصال به پايگاه داده");

mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'", $con);
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'", $con);
mysql_query("SET character_set_connection = 'utf8'", $con);

$selected=mysql_select_db($db_name, $con) or die("خطا در انتخاب پايگاه داده");
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET  utf8");
$ins="INSERT INTO $db_table (user_id,title,body) VALUES('$user_id','$title','$body')";
$saved=mysql_query($ins );
mysql_close($con); 
?>


<div class='container'>
<input type='submit'  name='Submit' value='ارسال اطلاعات' />


</div>
```

Comment: You have no such values as $title and $body ?!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem, myself.

We should use of two pages:

1. Sending input boxes via form to another page.
2. Insert input boxes via these codes:

   `$ins="INSERT INTO $db_table (user_id,title,body) VALUES('$user_id','" .` 
   `mysql_escape_string($_POST['title']) . "','" .` 
   `mysql_escape_string($_POST['body']) . "')";`

Answer (score 0):

You have the

```
 $user_id = $fgmembersite->UserID();
```

But where

```
 $title
```

and

```
 $body
```

come from ? If you want to assign $body a value of the textarea with the ID `body` you have to use JS Ajax call for example or simply hardcoding it (which is not recommended).

Comment: here is title and body:
<div class='container' dir="rtl" >
<label for='title'>موضوع: </label>
<input type='text' name='title' id='title'/><br/>

</div>

<div class='container' dir="rtl" >
<label for='body'>توضیحات: </label> <br />

Comment: They are HTML elements. You can't simply that say $body. I suppose you have some missunderstanding between html php and ...